# Installed Programs/Computer Info for Web Application

Tags: java, php, installed-applications

I'm currently developing a support system for a university. The system is written in PHP and I would like to be able to get a current list of software and basic computer information on a computer. Basically when one of the faculty or staff creates a ticket from our web interface, I would like to have a Java Applet or similar that could be run and would return the information to the help desk PHP script. Does something like this exist?

Comment: With the help of Jerry Coffin I was able to track down some software. The agent I found was http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/. It's not a packaged solution for what I'm looking for, but it gets me going in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of programs that do this sort of thing. Googling for "CMDB" should give you a reasonable start -- a couple of them are open source, though others aren't even close to free (e.g., [BMC Atrium](http://www.bmc.com/products/brand/bmc-atrium-0726.html)).

To keep things closer to topical (i.e., programming related), one of the main frameworks for this sort of situation is called Web-Based Enterprise Management (WBEM). On Windows this is implemented as [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx). On Linux there are a couple of implementations including [OpenWBEM](http://www.openwbem.org/) and [HP WBEM](http://h71028.www7.hp.com/enterprise/cache/13219-0-0-225-121.html).

Comment: After doing some digging I was able to find some software the kind of did what I want. It looks like there isn't much out there in terms of solutions to what I'm doing. I'm going to start look at packaging one of these solutions.

The software that I ended up finding was http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/. It had an Agent that I could run via command-line and dump data to an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

In Java?  You'd probably have a hard time even finding, let alone making, an applet that can get that info without already having some software installed on the user's end.  The biggest features of java are (1) that it runs in a virtual machine (read: getting to the underlying OS/hardware is not something it likes to do), and (2) that in a browser, applets generally run in a "sandbox" that keeps the applet from doing anything remotely dangerous.  Basically the most it can do is tie up resources.

Number 2 can be worked around by signing the applet, but that'll require you either buy a code signing certificate or install a self-signed certificate on any computer that'll run your app.

Number 1 might be worked around with some help from Runtime.exec and ...\wmic.exe, but that assumes the WMI stuff is installed -- which is rarely the case unless someone does a full install.